# jQuery Form submission with append field not working

Tags: jquery

I want to submit a form through a javascript function and want to add a field during form submission. Below are the HTML and JS codes:

```
function next_func() {


    $("#discountTotalAmountShipping").submit(function(eventObj) {
      $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', "something")
        .attr('value', "something")
        .appendTo('#discountTotalAmountShipping');
      return true;
    });

}
```

```html
<form id="discountTotalAmountShipping" action="somewhere" method="post">
  ... bla bla
</form>


<button onclick="next_func();" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">NEXT > </button>
```

When I tried to submit the form, I see there is no console error but the form is not submitting.

Comment: What have you screwed up your question? Check it out!

Comment: I tried to add jquery and all screwed up.

Comment: I fixed the question.

Comment: Ha ha. Sure man... `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that complexity. Just perform the action inside the click handler of the button and then trigger the submit action on form. As clear from the HTML, you don't have a submit button. Hence, you might not even need the submit handler:

```
function next_func() {
    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
      .attr('name', "something")
      .attr('value', "something")
      .appendTo('#discountTotalAmountShipping');
    $("#discountTotalAmountShipping").submit();

  }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="discountTotalAmountShipping" action="somewhere" method="post">
  ... bla bla
</form>


<button onclick="next_func();" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">NEXT > </button>
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/4015/
Check the HTML from the browser console to see the results.